# How to edit events in google calendar (API) that are shared across domain?

Tags: api, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

My organization has some domain wide calendar resources (to depict meeting rooms). I need to be able to edit the resource's calendar. What permissions would I need for it?

A [reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1034381) (under heading - Permission Settings) on Google Workspace Admin says that with *Make changes to events privilege, users can see event details and modify any event, but the option is available only when the resource is shared with specific people, not the entire organization.*

So, if the resource is shared with whole organization I have no choice. But isn't there some admin role (except super admin) or privilege that can enable me to edit domain wide resources?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your organization has one particular resource, whose calendar has some events that you want to edit. In that case in particular the resource is shared with the entire organization. If that is correct then, as you accurately pointed out, only the [superadmin](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986) can edit that calendar events. As an alternative you could create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount) with edit privileges over the resources and grant it [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) to edit those events as if the superadmin were doing so. Then you could use that service account to call the Calendar API as needed, per example the [`Events.update`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) method.